# About jquery storing local variable when writing plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am a newbie of using jQuery for writing plugin and currently facing a case on local variable handling,

and here is some code for all reference

```
    <div class="apple"></div>
    <div class="apple"></div>
    <script>
    var apple = [1,3];

    $(function(){
        $.fn.Hello = function(){

           return this.each(function(){
             var apple = 0;
             $.fn.extend({

                 setApples:function(num_of_apples){
                     apple = num_of_apples
                 },
                 getApples:function(){
                      return apple;
                 }
             });
           });
        }


        var i = 0;
        var $apples = $('.apple').Hello(); 
        $apples.each(function(){
            console.log(apple[i]);
            $(this).setApples(apple[i]);
            i++;
        });

        var j = 0;
        $('.apple').each(function(){

            console.log("Apple "+j+":"+$(this).getApples());
            j++;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I would like the result be 
Apple 0:1
Apple 1:3

But the last setting will always overwrite the last result. 
Actual Results:
Apple 0:3
Apple 1:3

I try to change the variable from `apple` to `this.apple`, but it will return me undefined result. May I know what is the wrong part in my code?

I try to go to search from google and there is another alternative by using `$(this).data('apple',value)`for set and `$(this).data('apple')` for getting the value but since I would like to have some calculation on the number of apple e.g. apple++, it will be tedious to do get and set by this method

e.g `$(this).data('apple',$(this).data('apple')+1);`, so would like to ask whether there is any other alternative for this case, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did `this.apple`, you would still get the last item from the apple array. This is because you will be then using the prototype to store the value of apple which is shared across all jQuery objects. E.g

```
$.fn.extend({
            apples:0,
            setApples:function(num_of_apples){
                 this.apples = num_of_apples
             },
             getApples:function(){
                  return this.apples;
             }
         });
```

If you want to store a value for each element the quick way will be to actually store it on the element but use your extension methods to grab it.

```
 $.fn.Hello = function(){
       return this.each(function(){
         $.fn.extend({
             setApples:function(num_of_apples){
                 this.data("apple", num_of_apples)
             },
             getApples:function(){
                  return parseInt(this.data("apple"));
             }
         });
       });
    }
```

You could add checks to make sure its a number being passed into the `setApples` function but for now this should work.

also as a side note you can improve your loops

```
var i = 0;

$.each(function(){
    i++
});
```

You can just use

```
$.each(function(index){
// use index here. 
}
```

here is the documentation for it : https://api.jquery.com/each/

Also a working example of the apples problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/y27tn5wg/